# Expandable box keeps growing

Tags: css, flexbox

**Browser: Chrome**

I was trying to setup a row of boxes that have an item inside of them that can expand. I'd like the items on the same row to be the same height. When the expandable items are collapsed I expect the containers to shrink accordingly. Somehow I created something where when the box expands it keeps increasing its size.

This example was extracted from an application. So the multiple layer's of divs probably wont make much sense to you. I just extracted the minimal pieces needed to reproduce the issue.

```js
const expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

for (let i = 0; i < expandButtons.length; i++) {
  const button = expandButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleExpand(button));
}

function toggleExpand(el) {
  const content = el.parentElement.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-block {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 500ms;
}

.content.is-expanded {
  max-height: 6em;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>ASDF</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
            <p>Third</p>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

Expanding the second box increases the height and it doesn't retract back when collapsed. Expanding/Collapsing the first fixes it. Why does this happen? ***(I'm interested in an explanation rather than a solution)***

**Edit**

I added the part of the example that justifies the `height: 100%` to avoid confusion. It is so that I can keep the buttons on the bottom. This involves adding `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` to `.card-block` and adding the `.spacer` class and corresponding element. These do not contribute to the problem but are the reason for the `height: 100%`.

BTW, and easy way to fix it is to remove `flex-direction: column` from `.card`. Again, I'm interested in the "why".

Comment: Are the `height: 100%` for `.wrapper` and `.card-block` necessary for some reason?

Comment: @ItayGanor Yeah, in the app I am pushing the button down to the bottom on all of them with a `flex-grow: 1` on a spacer. I took that bit out since it wasn't part of the problem but the `height: 100%` was necessary to produce the issue.

Comment: No matter why this happens, when using `height: 100%` on `.wrapper` you need to ask yourself, 100% of what? ... since its parent has not a defined height, those 100% will resolve to `auto`, and the `.card-block` will do the same. It appears to somewhat behave in Chrome, thought this won't work cross browsers.

Comment: @LGSon What do you mean that the height will resolve to auto? If I set them to auto it doesn't have the same behavior. The 100% I was going for is the calculated height of the tallest element in the row.

Comment: I posted an answer. I don't mean `auto` will work, I mean that an element having `height: 100%` picks up those 100% from its parent, but for that to work, also the parent need a height, which your doesn't have, hence the `100%` will resolve to `auto`

Comment: @LGSon why is the behavior different between the first and second boxes?

Comment: It appears to be a bug in Chrome, as this does not happen in the other browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note, the odd behavior appears to be a bug in Chrome, as this does not happen in the other browsers.*

<strike>No matter why this happens,</strike> when using `height: 100%` on `.wrapper` you need to ask yourself, 100% of what?

An element having `height: 100%` picks up those 100% from its parent, but for that to work, also the parent need a height, which your `card` doesn't have, hence the `100%` will resolve to `auto`.

And since `wrapper` will be resolved `auto`, so will also the `.card-block`, as its parent (the `wrapper`) doesn't have a defined height either. (It appears to somewhat behave in Chrome, thought this won't work cross browsers.)

The solution is to use Flexbox all the way.

Stack snippet

```js
const expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

for (let i = 0; i < expandButtons.length; i++) {
  const button = expandButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleExpand(button));
}

function toggleExpand(el) {
  const content = el.parentElement.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  /*height: 100%;                removed  */
  flex: 1;                   /*  added, fill parent height  */
  display: flex;             /*  added  */
  /*align-items: stretch         this is the default and make its item,
                                 the "card-block", fill its parent height  */
}

.card-block {
  /*height: 100%;                removed  */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 500ms;
}

.content.is-expanded {
  max-height: 6em;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>ASDF</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
            <p>Third</p>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use height: auto, rather than height: 100%;

```js
const expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

expandButtons.forEach(x => {
  x.addEventListener("click", () => toggleExpand(x));
});

function toggleExpand(el) {
  const content = el.parentElement.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  height: auto;
}

.card-block {
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 500ms;
}

.content.is-expanded {
  max-height: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>ASDF</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
            <p>Third</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need height:100%. There is more to the app. This is just the minimal reproducible example. If you take about any one part out the problem will go away. But I need those parts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you mean this. I just add `align-items:baseline;` to `.card` class. Also I remove `margin-top` from `.card-block > p` class.

```js
const expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

for (let i = 0; i < expandButtons.length; i++) {
  const button = expandButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleExpand(button));
}

function toggleExpand(el) {
  const content = el.parentElement.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-block {
  height: 100%;
}

.card-block > p {
   margin-top: 0;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 500ms;
}

.content.is-expanded {
  max-height: 6em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>ASDF</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
            <p>Third</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain what you changed? It still expands the box and it doesn't contract when it collapses. It just doesn't keep growing now.

Comment: Of course I added align-items:baseline; to .card class. Also I remove margin-top from p tag.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use

```
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
```

Rather than `.wrapper {height: 100%}`.

```js
const expandButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.expand');

for (let i = 0; i < expandButtons.length; i++) {
  const button = expandButtons[i];
  button.addEventListener("click", () => toggleExpand(button));
}

function toggleExpand(el) {
  const content = el.parentElement.querySelector('.content');
  content.classList.toggle('is-expanded');
}
```

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.card-block {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  transition: max-height 500ms;
}

.content.is-expanded {
  max-height: 6em;
}

.spacer {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <p>ASDF</p>
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
            <p>Third</p>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card-block">
          <div class="content">
            <p>First</p>
            <p>Second</p>
          </div>
          <div class="spacer"></div>
          <button type="button" class="expand">Expand</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

According to my understanding, `height: 100%` confuses the element, as its parent's height is the expanded one (after the transition), so it want to fill it. Using `flex: 1;` and `display: flex`, the element will fill the remaining height, and will be a flexbox too, meaning its child won't change the `.card` height too.

Comment: What do you mean by "confuses the element". Why doesn't `height: 100%` confuse the first element?

Comment: @bygrace which element is the first?

Comment: The box on the left.

Comment: When the second card has some more items in its `.content`, this problem doesn't seem to occur at all. Furthermore, adding `overflow-y: scroll` to `.content` will fix the issue too. That means, that this issue is a Chrome bug, and it is related to scaling divs **with scrollbars**. That's why it happens with the second card and not with the first.